# Foxpro 7 Test for 'File is in Use' prior to INSERT

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a wrapper to the VFP TABLEUPDATE() function which, among other things, logs additions and changes to other tables that are made.  The log table gets thrashed on occasion, due to multiple users saving and editing throughout the app, which results in a 'File is in use' error on my log table.  The table is not open when the INSERT is called.

I am reasonably sure no process has the file opened exclusively.  Ideally, I want to

- Check and see if the file is available to open
- Write to the file using INSERT INTO
- Get out as fast as I can

Records are never edited, only INSERTed.  Is there a way I can test the table before issuing the INSERT?

Answer (score 1):

If you receive File is in use (Error 3), then according to Visual Fox Manual: You have attempted a USE, DELETE, or RENAME command on a file that is currently open. So you say DELETE or RENAME is out of the question.
 
It must be the USE IN SELECT("cTableName").
If EXCLUSIVE is OFF, there is no need to check if the file is open.
Do not open the table before INSERT. Just execute the INSERT and there will be no need to close the table afterwards.
And so you can get rid of the UNLOCK IN cTableName USE IN SELECT("cTableName").

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you're holding the table open for too long and that any preliminary checks that you add will just tie the table up for longer. Do you close the table after your INSERT?

You say that the log table isn't open at the start of the process. This means that Fox will open the table for you silently so that the SQL can run. Are you opening it exclusive and are you explicitly closing it afterwards?

Comment: Yes, I'm worried that fooling with the table any more than necessary is only going to compound the problem. There were two functions in my INSERT, DATETIME() and JUSTSTEM() - I removed these, assigning them to variables before the INSERT and then INSERTed the variables. The three consecutive lines of code appear thus:  
    `INSERT INTO cTableName (variables....) VALUES (values...)  
    UNLOCK IN cTableName  
    USE IN SELECT("cTableName")  `  
EXCLUSIVE is OFF

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried locking the table in your insert routine?

```
IF FLOCK("mytable")
   INSERT INTO ......
ELSE
  WAIT WINDOW "Unable to lock"
ENDIF
```

Perhaps put this into a DO WHJILE loop?